# Show that minimal CFG is undecidable via mapping reduction

Tags: computability, context-free, decidability

Actually the problem below is an exercise in Sipser's textbook (Problem 5.36). However, from my perspective, it is not so trivial so that I post this question on this site instead of CS.SE.

The question itself was asked on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1105117/134950):

> Say that a CFG (context-free grammar) is *minimal* if none of its rules can be removed without changing the language generated. Let $MIN_{\textsf{CFG}}$ = $\{\, \langle G \rangle \ | \ G$ is a minimal CFG$\}$.
> a) Show that $MIN_{\textsf{CFG}}$ is Turing-recognizable.
> b) Show that $MIN_{\textsf{CFG}}$ is undecidable.

The OP figured out a), the relatively simple part, by himself. And I answered b) few days ago, by reducing to $ALL_{\textsf{minCFG}}$:

---

It suffices to focus on the case $\Sigma = \{0,1\}$. We argue that $ALL_{\textsf{minCFG}} \leq_T MIN_{\textsf{CFG}}$. That is, we can determine whether a **minimal** CFG can generate all possible strings, by using the oracle for $MIN_{\textsf{CFG}}$.

Let $G$ denote the minimal CFG we are interested. Since $G$ is minimal, there exists a length $p$ such that, for each rule $R$ in $G$ there exists a string $w_R$ with $|w_R|<p$ that can be generated by $G$, but not with $R$ deleted.
Note here that $p$ is computable in a brute force manner.
Construct $G^+_{a_1a_2\cdots a_p}$ where $a_i \in \Sigma$, by adding following rules in $G$:
$$
S \to a_1 a_2 \cdots a_pT \\
T \to T0 \ | \ T1 \ | \ \epsilon
$$
First, consider what will happen if $G^+_{a_1a_2\cdots a_p}$ is *not* minimal, thus, there exists a rule $R$ in $G^+$ being dispensable. By our construction it is clear that each rule $R$ in $G$ is indispensable.

- If $S \to a_1 a_2 \cdots a_pT$ or $T \to \epsilon$ is dispensable, then we have $a_1 a_2 \cdots a_p \Sigma^* \subseteq L(G)$.
- If $T \to T0$ is dispensable, then we have $(a_1 a_2 \cdots a_p \Sigma^* - a_1 a_2 \cdots a_p 1^*) \subseteq L(G)$. Because whether $a_1 a_2 \cdots a_p1^* \subseteq L(G)$ is easy to determine by some classical algorithm, we can also determine whether $a_1 a_2 \cdots a_p \Sigma^* \subseteq L(G)$.
- It is similar for $T \to T1$.

Therefore, if $G^+_{a_1a_2\cdots a_p}$ is not minimal, we can determine whether $a_1 a_2 \cdots a_p \Sigma^* \subseteq L(G)$. What if it is minimal? In this case we will immediately know $L(G) \neq \Sigma^*$. So we can suppose that all possible $G^+_{a_1a_2\cdots a_p}$ is not minimal. Then by checking whether $a_1 a_2 \cdots a_p \Sigma^* \subseteq L(G)$ one by one and checking those strings of less-than-$p$ length, we can still decide whether $L(G) = \Sigma^*$.

**Update.** (Oct 12, 2020) After a short discussion with @xdavidliu I realized that the argument above can directly prove what we want, without a justification of uncomputability of $ALL_{\textsf{minCFG}}$. Recall that the reduction we have established achieves the following: Given a minimal CFG $G$, determine whether $L(G) = \Sigma^*$. Now if we want to decide whether $L(G_0) = \Sigma^*$ for an arbitrary CFG $G_0$, just simply feed into the (reduction) algorithm all minimal sub-CFG (test each sub-CFG by the $MIN_{\mathsf{CFG}}$ oracle to determine whether it is minimal) of $G_0$ and see if there is one that generates all strings.

---

However, there are still two questions:

- <strike>Can we find a simple proof for undecidability of $ALL_{\textsf{minCFG}}$?</strike>
- Since this problem appears in Chapter 5, in which Turing reduction has not introduced. I personally believe that there is an elegant proof using only mapping reduction. Can we do it?

---

**Update.** (Nov 5th, 2017) We found that, roughly speaking, we could prove $A_{\textsf{TM}} \leq_T ALL_{\textsf{minCFG}}$ by the same way as one for $A_{\textsf{TM}} \leq_T ALL_{\textsf{CFG}}$, just adding some stuff to show that the grammar we used in proving $A_{\textsf{TM}} \leq_T ALL_{\textsf{CFG}}$ is already minimal. However, I could not assert that this way is quite simple.

**Comment.** @Sylvain gives an elegant proof below, by showing
$$ PCP \leq_T FullPCP \leq_m MIN_{\textsf{CFG}}$$
in which I personally thought the key is that context-free language is closed under $h^{-1}$ he defined.

Comment: Please define $ALL_{\textsf{minCFG}}$.

Comment: @Aryeh I have defined it informally in my answer. Does informality cause some serious problem?

Comment: No but I'd like to see your formal definition before I comment intelligently.

Comment: @Aryeh OK. Since there is an enumerator $E$ for $MIN_{\textsf{CFG}}$, we can use $E$ to encode all minimal CFGs to binary string, can't we?

Comment: Before I can comment on your arguments or offer mine, I need to understand your definitions. Can you please define $ALLminCFG$?

Comment: @Aryeh My classmate found a short formal definition: $ALL_{\textsf{minCFG}} = ALL_{\textsf{CFG}} \cap MIN_{\textsf{CFG}}$. Does it help?

Comment: Yes it does. Will think...

Comment: Modify the usual proof of undecidability of ambiguity, which is from a reduction from the Post Correspondence Problem.

Comment: @Sylvain Would you please point out where we should make a change to the original grammar for proving undecidability of ambiguity?

Comment: @xdavidliu I have updated the post. Thank you for letting me rethink of this problem!

Comment: @Lwins Thanks; also what about the comment that chapter 5 doesn't use Turing reductions? It uses them _extensively_ before even introducing mapping reductions, right?

Comment: @xdavidliu I have no much memory on this. Maybe they are informal? You can edit my question if you are sure since I have no means to check currently.

Comment: [See here for an alternative explanation for this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3864146/185635)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution based on a reduction from Post Correspondence Problem.  The general idea is similar to the ones used in reductions from PCP to the emptiness of intersection and ambiguity in context-free grammars.  I am afraid I am using a Turing reduction for a preliminary claim---which I would consider fair game considering the number of variants of PCP `out there'.

**Preliminaries.** 
A PCP instance is a finite set of pairs $\Pi=(u_i,v_i)_{i<n}$ of finite words over a finite alphabet $\Sigma$.  A *solution* is a sequence of indices $j_0,\dots,j_m$ with $u_{j_0}\cdots u_{j_m}=v_{j_0}\cdots v_{j_m}$.  The set of *indices* $I(\Pi)$ of a PCP instance $\Pi$ is the set of indices $i<n$ that appear in some solution; formally $$I(\Pi)=\{ i < n\mid \exists i_0,\dots,i_m <n\mathbin.u_{j_0}\cdots u_{j_m}=v_{j_0}\cdots v_{j_m}\text{ and }\exists 0\leq k\leq m\mathbin.i=j_k\}\;.$$
Then the PCP instance has a solution iff $I(\Pi)\neq\emptyset$.

**Claim.**  The following decision problem called *full PCP* is also undecidable:

- *instance* $\Pi$
- *question* $I(\Pi)=\{0,\dots,n-1\}$?

*Proof.*  By a Turing reduction from PCP.  Assume full PCP is decidable, and consider a PCP instance $\Pi$.  For a subset $J\subseteq\{0,\dots,n-1\}$, let $\Pi_J=(u_i,v_i)_{i\in J}$.  Then $\Pi$ has a solution iff $I(\Pi)\neq\emptyset$ iff there exists $J\subseteq\{0,\dots,n-1\}$ such that $\Pi_J$ is a positive instance of the full PCP.  Thus it suffices to check all the subsets $J$ with the algorithm for the full PCP; if at least one succeeds, the original PCP instance was positive, otherwise it was negative. $\Box$

**The first grammar** $G_1$ is constructed from a full PCP instance $\Pi$ in order to recognise
$$\begin{aligned}L_1&=\{ \$u_{j_0}\cdots \$u_{j_m}\#(\$v_{j_0}\cdots \$v_{j_m})^R\mid j_0,\dots,j_m < n\}\;,\\L'_1&=L_1\cup\{\#\}\end{aligned}$$
where $\cdot^R$ denotes the reversal operation, and $\$,\#$ are fresh symbols not in $\Sigma$.  Indeed, we can define $G_1=(\{S_1\},\Sigma\uplus\{\$,\#\},P_1,S_1)$ with $$P_1=\{S_1\to \$u_j S_1 v_j^R\$\mid j<n\}\cup\{S_1\to\#\}.$$ Then $L'_1=L(G_1)$.
Without loss of generality, we can assume $(u_i,v_i)\neq(u_j,v_j)$ for all $i\neq j<n$, and the grammar $G_1$ is minimal: the $\$$ symbols are indeed here to ensure minimality (as otherwise there might exist two different sequences of indices yielding the same words).

**The second grammar** generates `centered non-palindromes'
$$L_2=\{w\#{w'}^R\mid w\neq w'\in\Sigma^*\}.$$  Note that a word $w\#{w'}^R$ in $L_2$ is such that $w$ and $w'$ share a longest common prefix $u$: $w=uv$ and $w'=uv'$ for some $v,v'\in\Sigma^*$ with

1. either $v=ax$ and $v'=bx'$ for some $a\neq b\in\Sigma$ and $x,x'\in\Sigma^\ast$,
2. or $v=ax$ and $v'=\varepsilon$ for some $a\in\Sigma$ and $x\in\Sigma^\ast$,
3. or $v=\varepsilon$ and $v'=ax'$ for some $a\in\Sigma$ and $x'\in\Sigma^\ast$.

Thus $L_2$ is generated by $G_2=(\{S_2,E,A\},\Sigma\uplus\{\#\},P_2,S_2)$ with $$\begin{aligned}P_2&=\{S_2\to aS_2a\mid a\in\Sigma\}\cup\{S_2\to E\}\\&\cup\{E\to aA\#Ab\mid a\neq b\in\Sigma\}\cup\{aA\#\mid a\in\Sigma\}\cup\{\#Aa\mid a\in\Sigma\}\\&\cup\{A\to aA\mid a\in\Sigma\}\cup\{A\to\varepsilon\}\end{aligned}$$
The idea is that $S_2$ generates $u E u^R$ for $u$ the longest common prefix of $w$ and $w'$, after which $E$ applies one of the three cases above.  Thus $L(G_2)=L_2$, and the grammar is minimal.

**Relating the two grammars.**  Let $h$ be the homomorphism from $(\Sigma\uplus\{\$,\#\})^*$ to $(\Sigma\uplus\{\#\})^*$ defined by $h(a)=a$ for all $a\in\Sigma$, $h(\#)=\#$, and $h(\$)=\varepsilon$; $h$ simply erases $\$$ symbols.  Then $\Pi$ has a solution iff $h(L_1)\not\subseteq L_2$.  We define $L'_2=h^{-1}(L_2)$ and construct the corresponding grammar $G'_2=(N'_2,\Sigma\cup\{\$,\#\},P'_2,S'_2)$ in the obvious way (add a nonterminal $D$ with productions $D\to \$D$ and $D\to\varepsilon$ and introduce $D$ symbols everywhere in the right hand sides of the productions in $P_2$); it is still minimal and $\Pi$ has a solution iff $L_1\not\subseteq L'_2$.

We are however interested in the full PCP on $\Pi$.  Construct $$G=(N_1\uplus N'_2\uplus\{S\},\Sigma\uplus\{\$,\#\},P_1\cup P'_2\cup\{S\to S_1,S\to S'_2\},S) .$$

- If $\Pi$ is a positive instance of the full PCP, then it has solutions, which describe words $\$u_{j_0}\cdots \$u_{j_m}\#(\$v_{j_0}\cdots \$v_{j_m})^R\not\in L'_2$ and moreover require every production of $G_1$.  Regarding $G'_2$, it suffices to consider words from $L_2\subseteq L'_2$ with no occurrence of $\$$, which do not belong to $L_1$ and therefore all the productions of $G'_2$ are needed.  Therefore, $G$ is minimal.
- Otherwise, there exists $i<n$ such that $i\not\in I(\Pi)$, and the production $S_1\to \$u_i S_1 v_i^R\$$ can be removed, since it cannot be part of a solution of $\Pi$, and therefore any generated word that uses this production is in $L(G'_2)$; thus $G$ is not minimal.  In particular, if $\Pi$ has no solution ($I(\Pi)=\emptyset$), then all the productions in $P_1$ except $S_1\to\#$ can be removed. $\Box$